# Бот парсер из telegram в discord

Tags: python, telegram, бот, discord

Возник такой интересный вопрос, как можно из определённого telegram канала, выводить сообщения в нужный канал discord. Подскажите пожалуйста или может есть какая-то статься по этому поводу,всем заранее спасибо!

P.S
Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы когда опубликовывается новая запись, бот сразу её отправлял а discord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу Python в точностях описать не могу, но самый простой способ - сделать отправку сообщений через вебхуки.

Т.е. на стороне телеграмма уже триггерить ивент и передавать данные в обычный POST запрос. Что передавать в запрос подробно описано [тут](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook).